# frame number on progress bar between section titles and frame title - metropolis beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, beamer-metropolis

I would like to have frames structured as follows:

-- sections titles --

-- frame number fraction (at right-most end) ON a progress bar --

-- frame title --

-- frame content --

With metropolis, exploiting older questions on StackExchange, I got here:

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=head]{metropolis} 
\metroset{numbering=fraction}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{1em}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{% 
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}  
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}

\begin{document}

\section{section title}

\begin{frame}{frame title}

first line

second line

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code manages to place sections and progress bar on top, with the latter element being covered by the former one, and use frame number fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `moloch` theme (a more modern fork of the `metropolis` theme) uses the headline template to show the progress bar. If you use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{...}` you are not covering the progress bar up, you are removing it completely. You can instead use `\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{<before>}{<after>}` to add things to the headline without actively removing the progress bar which is already there:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=head]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\moloch@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{1em}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{% 
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \par
}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-5.5ex]current page.north east) {\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}  
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=mLightBrown}

\begin{document}

\section{section title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}

first line

second line

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}

first line

second line

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I change the color of the frame numbers? I have tried with `\setbeamercolor{frame number in head/foot}{fg = mLightBrown}`, but it does not work, it stays black.

Comment: @oibaFox See my updated answer

Comment: @oibaFox (if you make the frame number orange, it won't be visible on the last pages)

Comment: yes, that is intentional :) it is not working, I am trying to understand what is interfering that is not in the MWE. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @oibaFox Does it work if you try exactly the mwe from my answer instead of your actual document?

Comment: yes, your MWE works as expected. I still have to understand what is interfering in my code though. I will accept your answer in the meanwhile.

Comment: @oibaFox Ok, that good - it means your beamer version is new enough to already have the `page number in head/foot` template. If you can narrow your code down enough to post, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}` with a hard coded colour, e.g. `\color{green}`?